# Search not working in Preview.app

Tags: macos, preview, search

Viewing a pdf with Preview, I do <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to bring up a search box and then enter a word and hit enter.

Basically nothing happens even if it's a word that's obviously present. Sometimes if I smash my hands all over the keyboard and spin around in my chair three times the search suddenly starts working again, but I haven't figured out how to do that trick reliably.

Comment: I have the same issue. Seems like the recent Sierra update messed up the Preview.app. It is all over the place.

Comment: +1 same problem here with 10.12.5 no mention of any fixes in 10.12.6 which is a pending update I have for installing: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201222 As an alternative try https://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/

Comment: The problem remains under macOS 10.13.1. If anything, it seems to have gotten worse over time.

Comment: I'll chime in with macOS 10.13.2. I upgraded from Mavericks to High Sierra and noticed this issue pretty quickly. +1.

Comment: "spin around in my chair three times the search suddenly starts working" 

Comment: Similar issue. When I search "Hello 123" it will highlight random "H" 's and random  "lo" 's. Seems like preview doesn't get concept of words.

Comment: I've encountered this issue sporadically for _years_, probably on the cats releases. It still occurs on Mojave evidently, and is extremely frustrating.

Comment: Quit Preview and start Preview again worked for me

Comment: Exit Preview. Then delete the container for Preview and restart the app.
The container directory is /Users/samiyuru/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview

Answer (score 32):

I selected the "Table of Contents" in "View Menu" and searched again. It is working. Check the screenshot:

[image]

Anyway, make sure that your PDF contains texts and not the image of some texts.

Comment: just saw this after upgrading to Mojave, not sure if it changed the app or reset my defaults, but this fixed it.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Worked for me on Mojave.  Weird.

Comment: It works if I select "Thumbnails" instead of "Table of Contents"...

Comment: "Thumbnails" also worked for me. Good grief Apple.

Comment: Actually it is any resetting to the open window that works. When you hear a beep on a search apple is communicating an error and from them on no search will be highlighted until you reset the open window. Closing the window by Cmd-W and then reopening clears the error everytime. Come on apple, fix it.

Comment: Initial conditions: Open pdf w/ side bar automatically displayed. "Highlights & Notes" is already selected. THEN Hide the sidebar - w/out selecting 'Table of Contents' -  then command-F worked  QWERKS:  enter find text before hide - does not work. Delete this  "pre-hide find text" with sidebar till hidden, then enter find text -  works. CURIOUS: ...

Comment: ... CURIOUS:  It seems like whatever convolutions I go through, if "Highlights & Notes" remains selected find does not work.  Apparently selecting "Hide sidebar" seems to de-select "Highlights & Notes". With "H & N" deselected, whatever particular slight of hand used, as long as "H & N" is not selected, FIND works as expected.

Answer (score 23):

"BTW, in order to get search working again, you have to close the window (command + w) and reopen on the pdf. Closing Preview all together (command + q) and reopening the pdf doesn't work. This is indeed bizarre."
https://discussions.apple.com/message/33927812#33927812

Comment: This was the only thing that worked. Cmd-W and then open th file again from 'recents'. Good grief Apple. Fix your pdf reading.

Comment: I'm running Catalina and this won't fix it for me.

Comment: I really did not expect it, but ⌘+W instead of ⌘+Q, then reopening the file did indeed fix the PDF search (Mojave, 10.14.16) -- takes it from finding nothing with all search strings to finding what you search for. I thought search was broken entirely, but instead there's just this unfortunate bug. In Apple's parlance: not a crasher, but _is_ a regression. There's a chance that it'll be fixed if an appropriate radar is filed.

Answer (score 6):

I've selected File->Export as PDF - reopened saved file and the Search worked.
Looks like some encoding issue.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth: in my case the problem seemed to appear when opening a pdf from Finder. Opening the same file via File>Open in Preview "solves" the problem. Unbelievable something as simple as this is still not fixed in Catalina

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue as well.  For me at least, the problem was that I got stuck searching the annotations or table of contents, and so generally didn't find what I was looking for there.  I was able to resolve this by clicking on the `x` box in the search panel to exit out of the old search and go back to searching through the whole document.